# Symfony, OneTwoMany, first child element in twig

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine, twig

Product and Image are two entities linked by a oneToMany association (one product has many images). I try to enumerate with TWIG each product with the first image (filename fied) like this :

```
class ProductRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getProductsWithImages() {

        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
                      ->leftJoin('e.images', 'i', 'with', 'i.order = :order')
                      ->setParameter('order' , 0)
                      ->select('e')
                      ->addSelect('i');

        return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

}

But I got this error :

```
Method "filename" for object "\entity\product" does not exist.
```

I understand why (product entity has no image field). What is the best pratice to get only one child element without add a reference on the parent (like a mainImage field) ?

Comment: show us your twig code - as problem is probably there

Answer (score 1):

As the [doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) explains :

> A one-to-many association has to be bidirectional, unless you are
>   using an additional join-table. This is necessary, because of the
>   foreign key in a one-to-many association being defined on the “many”
>   side. Doctrine needs a many-to-one association that defines the
>   mapping of this foreign key.

I have this kind of relation in my current project and I simply defined bidirectional one-to-many association. So in your twig view you should be able to do for example :

```
{# first Image linked to the Product #}
{{ product.images.first }}
```

The attribute `images` is an ArrayCollection.

Hope it helps

Comment: With this approach you lazyload all image of each product.